# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el ciclo while finalice si introduzco las letras ESC si el dato que ingresa por el prompt es un número?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

Comunidad ¡los saludo!
Quisiera que me ayudaran a entender el porque si ingreso las letras ESC el ciclo while no finaliza. Considero que el problema está en que la variable aula se transforma en número cuando se ingresa el dato por prompt pero cuando realizo la comparación en el while estoy comparando con un string, sin embargo le he eliminado la propiedad Number(), he sustituido por isNaN y he hecho otras pruebas con !== en vez de != y nada. Gracias de antemano.

```
let aula = Number(prompt("Ingrese el número de aula que busca"))

while(aula != "ESC") {
    switch (aula) {
        case 1:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso");
           break;
        case 2:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la derecha");
           break;
        case 3:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la izquierda");
           break;
        case 4:
            alert("El aula se encuentra en el segundo piso");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Ese aula no existe");
            break;
    }
    
    aula = Number(prompt("Ingrese el aula que busca"))

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé cómo habrás hecho el testing pero sucede exactamente lo que decís. Ahí corregí el código para que se comporte como buscás.

```
let aula = prompt("Ingrese el número de aula que busca")

while(aula != "ESC") {
    switch (parseInt(aula)) {
        case 1:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso");
           break;
        case 2:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la derecha");
           break;
        case 3:
           alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la izquierda");
           break;
        case 4:
            alert("El aula se encuentra en el segundo piso");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Ese aula no existe");
            break;
    }
    
    aula = prompt("Ingrese el aula que busca")

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    //let 
    var ala = "ESC" ;
     let aula= prompt("Ingrese el número de aula que busca")
    
    while(ala != "ESC") {
        switch (parseInt(aula)) {
            case 1:
               alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso");
               break;
            case 2:
               alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la derecha");
               break;
            case 3:
               alert("El aula se encuentra en el primer piso, a la izquierda");
               break;
            case 4:
                alert("El aula se encuentra en el segundo piso");
                break;
            default:
                alert("Ese aula no existe");
                break;
        }
        
        aula = prosmpt("Ingrese el aula que busca")
    
    }//return.null;
    </script>
    <scrop
```

Comment: return.null get

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.